# How to send Kafka message to multiple client racks?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have a Spring Boot Application that uses kafka to produce and consume messages to/from other applications.

I implemented a new producer whose messages should be sent to different clients located in different development servers. Kafka configuration it's specificated in the application.yml of the project. This was the previous configuration:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: server.a:port
    producer:
      properties:
        client.rack: server.a
    consumer:
      clientId: a-client-id
      groupId: a-group-id
      properties:
        client.rack: server.a
    jaas:
      options:
        username: an-username
        password: a-password
```

Now with the new producer I need to produce message to a second server, `server.b` so:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: 
      - server.a:port
      - server.b:port
    producer:
      properties:
        client.rack: 
          - server.a
          - server.b
    consumer:
      clientId: a-client-id
      groupId: a-group-id
      properties:
        client.rack: server.a
    jaas:
      options:
        username: an-username
        password: a-password
```

However, this seems to be sending the produced messages to `server.b` only.

I'm not sure if my config it's wrong or not. As far as I read this seems to be the properly way of doing it but, obviously, I did something wrong because it's not working. Bit lost here.

Comment: `jaas.options` [isn't a valid config, by the way](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.kafka.additional-properties)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't how Kafka works. Clients always send to the leader broker. Leaders can exist on any rack, and clients cannot control where they send data other than that leader first, and then configure `acks` to allow for replication to other followers on other racks.

Also, `client.rack` is a string, not a list.

Comment: So which will be the better approach if i want to have a kafka producer but I have the consumer in different servers?

Comment: Location of your clients don't matter. They can never specify which brokers to communicate with directly. That is decided only by the broker's leader-election protocol.